# Can iOS 12 app extension write to Healthkit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

When first released, [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html) stated that Healthkit could not be accessed from app extensions:

> For example, in iOS 8.0, the HealthKit framework and EventKit UI
>   framework are unavailable to app extensions.

WatchOS 1 also could not access Healthkit, but [that changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602960/can-i-access-healthkit-data-from-iwatch-extension) with WatchOS 2

Does anyone know if that restriction is still present in current versions of iOS? [The name of one API call](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614153-handleauthorizationforextensionw?changes=latest_minor&preferredLanguage=occ) and [one SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016282/save-delete-to-healthkit-with-watchkit-and-widget-today-extension) give me hope, but still unclear if that only applies to WatchOS extensions.

Can't find any clear statement, specifically looking for use in intents/Siri Shortcut functionality. Only looking to write data, not read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions have been able to use HealthKit since at least iOS 10.0 and watchOS 3.0.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The Documentation says healthkit and eventkit are unavailable on iOS8. It doesn't mention about versions above 8. Now, I have come accross apps that show calendar events in widgets. So eventkit is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation. I have my app with a widget. I tried to use 'import EventKitUI' in one of my swift file in the main app. Now, if I check mark the target membership to include my widget, it won't work. I would get error "Could not build Objective-C module 'EventKitUI'" Once I removed the check mark, everything works just fine.

Don't know the reason behind this but it is just I found out.